# Marking squares in a Conway's game of life simulator changes color to fast

Tags: python, conways-game-of-life

I'm making a Conway's game of life simulator and I've got some trouble with marking the squares in a color. I'm using a matrix for the squares and when I click on a square, I change the value from 0 to 1. Or that's what it's supposed to be like.
I've first tried this code below, but the problem was that when I clicked once it changed rapidly from marked to non-marked to marked and so on.

```
if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
    if grid[y][x] == 0:
        mouse_x,mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        x = mouse_x // (size + 1)
        y = mouse_y // (size + 1)
        grid[y][x] = 1

    elif grid[y][x] == 1:
        mouse_x,mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        x = mouse_x // (size + 1)
        y = mouse_y // (size + 1)
        grid[y][x] = 0
```

Than I've tried an other code:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        if grid[y][x] == 0:
            mouse_x,mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            x = mouse_x // (size + 1)
            y = mouse_y // (size + 1)
            grid[y][x] = 1

        elif grid[y][x] == 1:
            mouse_x,mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()                        
            x = mouse_x // (size + 1)
            y = mouse_y // (size + 1)
            grid[y][x] = 0
```

But the problem here is that the squares don't get marked anymore.

Comment: Any solution involving `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` is going to have this kind of problem.  Your second code is the right idea (the `MOUSEBUTTONUP` event will occur exactly once per click), but is presumably failing because you are using `x` and `y` before actually calculating them from the click location.

Comment: @jasonharper What should I do instead? Should I set the `mouse_x,mouse_y` before the `if grid[y][x] == 1` ?

Comment: Before the `if grid[y][x] == 0:`, actually - no use having those three lines of code duplicated in two places.

Comment: @jasonharper I've tried it that way and it still doesn't work

Comment: You should probably use `True`/`False` instead of `1`/`0`.

Comment: @SolomonUcko now it works but I have to wait some time between 2 clicks (verry long and irregulary): sometimes I have to wait like 6 seconds, sometimes 'only' 3

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a kind of cool down every click with time.time().

```
# Start of program
import time
cooldown = 0

cooleddown = time.time() - cooldown > 0.7
if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] and cooleddown:
     cooleddown = time.time()
     if grid[y][x] == 0:
        mouse_x,mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        x = mouse_x // (size + 1)
        y = mouse_y // (size + 1)
        grid[y][x] = 1

    elif grid[y][x] == 1:
        mouse_x,mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        x = mouse_x // (size + 1)
        y = mouse_y // (size + 1)
        grid[y][x] = 0
```

What `time.time()` does is return the current seconds since midnight January 1 1970. So if you test if it has past a certain amount of time before checking again this might help the problem.

***This Is not tested you may need to play around with the wait 0.7 seconds may to little or to long i don’t know**

Comment: Could it be that in the loop it must be 'cooldown = time.time()' instead of 'cooleddown = time.time()'?

Comment: It works but it isn't the code I'm searching for because you have to wait between two clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting x and y before using them, also use booleans (not tested):

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        mouse_x,mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        x = mouse_x // (size + 1)
        y = mouse_y // (size + 1)
        grid[y][x] = not grid[y][x]
```